# Loss of significance example

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Consider $a=0.123567, b =0.123456$ and $\epsilon=10^{-7}$

When I compute, then I get $a-b= 0.0001100$ then the error is at the third decimal place. Why is that the case?

Comment: I don't really understand your question? What does "significance" mean? Why do you see anything wierd with the result of $a-b$? $a$ and $b$ are different at the fourth decimal place

Comment: The error in a and b is at the seventh decimal point, whereas the error in a-b seems to be a the third decimal place.

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: @StevenHunt Are you sure this is not just caused by a typo?

Comment: @Klaus: Yes I am sure.

Comment: So you are asking why $0.123567 - 0.123456 = 0.000111$? Are you serious?

Comment: Why is the error at the third decimal place.

Comment: The error is at the _fourth_ decimal place because $a$ and $b$ differ at the fourth decimal place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given a decimal number $a=0.123567$ without further context, then the usual reading is that it could stand for any number in the interval $(0.1235665,0.1235675)$, which is the meaning behind the words "exact to 6 decimal places". Now if you compute the difference $$a-b=(0.1235665,0.1235675)−(0.1234555,0.1234565)=(0.0001100,0.0001120)$$ in this interval sense, then the seventh digit after the decimal dot is still uncertain, but now also the sixth could take two values.

To answer your question, in counting "significant" or "exact decimals" the leading zeros of a number are ignored, so that in $a-b=0.000111$ you have, depending on how strict you count, 2 or 3 exact decimals, the one after that is uncertain. This is the loss of "significant decimal places", going from 6 to 3 or 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why could  the sixth take two values?

Comment: Because numbers in the interval difference $(0.1235665,1235675)-(0.1234555,1234565)=(0.000110,0.000112)$ have two different values ($0,1$) for the 6th digits, and could be rounded to even 3 different last digits if rounded to 6 decimals after the dot.

Comment: Perfect. I got it :)

Comment: 1. I think you have a typo, the interval should be (0.1235665,0.1235675)

Comment: 2. I think your answer is wrong. But this is to long for a comment. Please see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3770843/11206)

Comment: First, thank you, typo corrected. And second, yes, somehow I ignored the $ϵ$, but that makes the argument of what "loss of significance" means not wrong, it just handles a case of less precision. The cancellation of the leading digits remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer of [Lutz](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3770843/11206) wrong. Without any context $a=0.123567$ may have the meaning that a is in $(0.1235665,1235675)$.  But on a computer $a=0.123567$ is rounded to the next number that can be represented on the computer. If $eps=10^{-7}$ this means, that in the neighborhood of $1$ the distance between consecutive machine numbers is a about $10^{-7}.$ In the neighborhood of 0.1 the distance is about $\frac {\text eps} {10} \approx 10^{-8}$. So $a$ is represented by a number  from $(0.123567-10^{-8},0.123567-10^{-8})$ and $b$ by a number from $(0.123456-10^{-8},0.123456-10^{-8}).$ So $$a-b \in (0.000111 - 2\cdot 10^{-8},0.000111 + 2\cdot 10^{-8})=(0.00011098,0.00011102)$$  and if we display $7$ decimal places after the decimal point should be displayed as $0.0001109$ or $0.0001110$, depending on the actual result.

Comment: You should go to the end, the number $0.000111=1.11\cdot 10^{-4}$ without history stands for the interval $(0.000111-10^{-11}, 0.000111+10^{-11})$, while the subtraction resulted in a much larger interval.